# failing to have multiple turtle go off in different directions due to unknown error

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-3.8, python-turtle

in python3.8 i am trying to have multiple turtle go off in different directions but whenever i execute the bellow code

```
import turtle

ivan = turtle.Turtle()
amy = turtle.Turtle()

ivan.forward(50)
ivan.left(90)
ivan.forward(20)

amy.right(90)
amy.forward(100)
```

the terminal spits this out after opening the turtle window

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3814, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2558, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

any help?

Comment: No `raise Terminator`  on my system ( Python 3.9 ). This is not really a problem. The Terminator is raised e.g. when you close the Turtle window when the script is still running. Don't worry about that. It's not an ERROR message ... only a hint, that you didn't handle closing the window in your code. It's not a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Try THIS:

```
import turtle

ivan = turtle.Turtle()
amy  = turtle.Turtle()

ivan.forward(50)
ivan.left(90)
ivan.forward(20)

amy.right(90)
amy.forward(100)

turtle.mainloop()
```